# Custom query function for Ember Data adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to override my default query function in my application adapter. I'm using query to get data from the backend, when the application goes offline I'd like to query only the data currently stored in the cache with `.peekAll()`.

I used this as a reference, but without much avail. https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_query

This is what I have so far.

**UPDATE**

```js
// adapters/application.js
  
// turns to cache when no connection available
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  // ...
  query(store, type, query) {
    let isOnline = this.get('isOnline'); // updates according to connection, returns true or false
    if (isOnline) {
      // execute regular query() when online
      return this._super(...arguments);
    } else {
      // return promise for query().then() to work
      return PromiseArray.create({
        promise: RSVP.resolve(store.peekAll(type.modelName))
      });
    }
  }
}
```

but my problem is I'm not able to execute the query function within the query function properly. Not sure what's the problem here, I tried wrapping this in promises or returning with `.then()`.

**UPDATE**

```js
// can't get this to work
query(store, type, query) {
  return PromiseArray.create({
    promise: RSVP.resolve(store.peekAll(type.modelName))
  });
}
```

I feel like once I get that right, the rest won't be much of a problem.

Any help, ideas or workarounds much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried isOnline ? this_super(..arguments) : your custom stuff ?

Comment: Hey that made query() work again, thanks! The problem is still the implementation of the store methods like .filter() . Don't really know what's the right way to do this.

Comment: No such method in JSONapiAdapter.

Comment: I think that's not the problem since I'm calling the methods on the store object. So within my custom query method, store.peekAll(type.modelName); for example works fine and returns the values. Returning the result doesn't work though.

Comment: You can't return the data from the store in the adapter. You would have to first serialize the data to JSONAPI format. but maybe its a better idea to extend the store itself. [Look into this addon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-query-cache) I wrote, its doing something very similar.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I have actually checked out the addon before, but since there was no description whatsoever I didn't bother trying it. The addon doesn't seem to work out of the box for me, it's throwing some errors and then query() breaks after the second time, but still this might get me closer to what I wanna do.